# how to get function call tree with miniprofiler

Tags: c#, mvc-mini-profiler

I installed and started using miniprofiler in my global.asax file. so far all works fine.

following set up I have,

```
protected void Application_Start()
{      
     StackExchange.Profiling.EntityFramework6.MiniProfilerEF6.Initialize();

     //miniprofiler
     if (databaseInstalled)
     {
        if (EngineContext.Current.Resolve<StoreInformationSettings>().DisplayMiniProfilerInPublicStore)
        {
            GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new ProfilingActionFilter());
        }
     }
}

protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     MiniProfiler.Start();    
}
```

I get the information about function times but only for the root functions. so it doesnt show me which sub functions are spending how much time inside a main function. this is usually I would retreive using VS profiler or other profilers like redgate. Is it possible to retreive it with miniprofiler?